# How to format a full sentence in caps using .upper function in Python?

Tags: python, string

I want to generate a line from my code so that it will appear in uppercase.

This is the code that I have so far:

---

```
a= 98
b= 88
c= 78
d = """ I want {} kilos of gram
and it want {} kilos of magi also i want
{} of ginger """

print(d.format(a,b,c) and (d.upper()))
```

---

The output should appear as:

"""I WANT {98} KILOS OF GRAM AND IT WANT {88} KILOS OF MAGI ALSO I WANT {78} OF GINGER """

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
a= 98
b= 88
c= 78
d = """ I want {} kilos of gram
and it want {} kilos of magi also i want
{} of ginger """

print(d.format(a,b,c).upper()) # modification is here
```

```py
Out[1]:
 I WANT 98 KILOS OF GRAM
AND IT WANT 88 KILOS OF MAGI ALSO I WANT
78 OF GINGER
```